# View looks around in first person, rather than orbiting around

Tags: 3d-view

If I hold down the middle mouse button and move my mouse around, the view *should* orbit around, instead just looks around, similar to how it does in fly-mode. If I press the button to enter/exit fly mode, it still does the same thing.

Comment: You are in *Fly Mode* press `Escape` or `Right Click` to cancel

Comment: I am aware fly mode exists, as I mentioned it in my post, I can confirm I am not in flight mode

Comment: screenshot? also have you tried restarting blender?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out my blender was just glitching and restarting it helped.

Comment: sorry this response answer was late, I completely forgot about this post for 2 years